# Ruby on Rails 4 When does devise call require_no_authentication method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, alert

I have a problem about message when using devise:

1.I don't want to show alert after login and redirect to top page of admin

2.I override method require_no_authentication of devise

```
  def require_no_authentication
    super
    flash.delete :alert
  end
```

3.In case of: I login with an acount is deleted (with soft delete, deleted_at != nil).It not show alert inactive("You account is deleted") for me.I want to keep this alert

4.I have a solution as below:

```
  def require_no_authentication
    super
    flash.delete :alert unless flash[:alert] ==
      I18n.t("devise.failure.admin.inactive")
  end
```

I can't cover all cases have flash alert with login logout

5.Can we have another implementation, can you show me all of case will call require_no_authentication method?
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For removing specific alert is easy you just need to unset that particular alert message in devise.en.yml file or corresponding translation file like below.

```
sessions:
  signed_in: ''
```

Put a check a check where you are rendering alerts.

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash" if msg.length > 0 %>
<% end %>
```

You can use css but not perfered.

```
.flash.alert:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

For require_no_authentication method it's a before action used by devise internally. It's not recommended to override this method. Let me know if you have a problem with this solution.